# Unity rotating camera with accelerometer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, accelerometer

I'm trying to rotate the camera around a cube with LookAt() function and using the accelerometer in an Android device. It works well. But I want the rotation to stop at some value in the Y axis. Here is my code so far:

```
public Transform target;    // The object to follow
public float topMargin = 0.2f;  // Top rotation margin

// The position of the target
private Vector3 point;

void Start () {
    point = target.transform.position;
    transform.LookAt (point);
}

void Update () {
    // Freeze
    if (transform.rotation.y >= topMargin) {
        transform.RotateAround (point, new Vector3 (0, 1, 0), 0);
    }
    // Freeze
    else if (transform.rotation.y <= -topMargin) {
        transform.RotateAround (point, new Vector3 (0, 1, 0), 0);
    } else {
        transform.RotateAround (point, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), Input.acceleration.x);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the camera reaches the top margin, I can't start rotating again in the opposite direction. I've tried with a flag variable but can't get the correct program logic (tried different if/else's). Any suggestion on how to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the (intended) rotation direction. If the result would lead to a rotation that is more appropriate (away from the boundary and towards the allowed area) you could "allow" the intended rotation to apply.
I guess using the accelerometer value to check for "intended direction" would be easiest and least error prone. (Rather than checking the rotation itself)